# <Error><Code>NotImplemented</Code><Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented<Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, go, boto3, aws-sdk-go

I am facing an issue while trying to upload objects from golang using presigned url (generated from python code in lambda),

It uploads fine when I test with curl command, however, in golang, i face below issue.

```
<Error>
  <Code>NotImplemented</Code>
  <Message>A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented</Message>
  <Header>Transfer-Encoding</Header>  
  <RequestId>KFHK9CHD356ZFA9M</RequestId> 
  <HostId>M8G5f0QVL132xZCRBBAgaobHEK/M9DPMUIKKxYptIrAaFe4Tg86s08+zkCj3sR9UC1SUzOMlzsI=</HostId>
</Error>
```

It should work in golang same way as curl command.

Can someone help me here please?

Comment: could you please share the code ? preferably bith the curl and golang code

Comment: Try [disabling compression](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Transport.DisableCompression) in Go.